# Uniqueness of Smooth Structure for Manifolds with Boundary

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Say $M$ is a topological manifold with boundary, and we provide two smooth structures for $M$ that give identical smooth structures for its interior. Does this force the two smooth structures to be identical, or is it possible for the interior charts to be compatible while the boundary charts remain incompatible?